# Get Users by Age Using User Birthdate Column From Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

**Brief:**

I have user `birthdate` column in my `users` table. User birthdate has a default date format: `Y-m-d`. Also, I have custom mutator to get user age in `User` model.

**Mutator code:**

```
public function getAgeAttribute($value) {
    if($this->birthday !== null) {
        $bday = new \DateTime("{$this->birthday}");
        $today = new \Datetime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $diff = $today->diff($bday);

        return $diff->y;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Question:**

How I can get users by **age** using `User` model?

Comment: what do you mean `by age` ? you mean that you want to fetch all users greater than 20 years?

Comment: Yes of course @hassan

Comment: what is the column type? datetime/date?

Comment: Column type string. If you think will change the type of field to date from string, I will change it. @hassan

Comment: you might want to use a local scope for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just take today's date and substract the number of years. then compare it to birthdays

```
Users::where('birthday', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-20 years')))->get();
```

Comment: adding to this answer, this logic can be enclosed on a local scope defined in the User model.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using MySQL there's also this alternative:

```
 $users = User::whereDate('birthdate' , '<', \DB::raw("CURDATE()-INTERVAL 20 YEAR"))->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also do it by this ways we will increase one year more and search between date like this

```
$from = Carbon::today()->subYears($request->age);
$to = Carbon::today()->subYears(($request->age)+1);
$users->whereBetween('birth_date',[$to, $from]);`
```

Comment: i think this is better approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection`'s `groupBy` method to group the users based on their age.

```
$users = User::all()->groupBy(function($user) {
             return $user->age;
         });
```

Then, you can get all users for a particular user like this.

```
$users->get(20);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you, `date()` function is php function which converts a string to datetime.

`$users = User::where('birthdate' , '<', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('your input field name')))->get();`